# Not receiving PHP contact form submissions

Tags: php, sendmail

I was wondering if you guys can figure out why I'm not receiving my contact form submissions. I tested it out with my secondary email but still haven't received it. I tried looking for answers here in SO and on Google but can't find any solution. I have 3 questions.

It is my code? 
Or did I not properly setup my Apache?
Is my php code secure from spam?

here's my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
$email_to = "myemail@mail.com";

$email_subject = "Contract work opportunity";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting. I will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

HTML

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="http://mysite.localdom/html_form_send.php/">
<table width="400px">
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="business_name">Business Name</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="business_name" maxlength="200">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="website">Website</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="website" maxlength="200">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="email">Email Address *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="telephone">Phone</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="comments">Message</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea  name="comments" maxlength="5000" cols="25" rows="6">ok ok ok</textarea>
</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitbutton">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: step 1, how is this hosted?

Comment: @Dagon I use Apache 2.4 as I learned through watching this youtube setup guide. My apologies, I am still learning about PHP, since I don't have the budget, im trying to work on my website on my own.

Comment: I forgot to add... I'm not exactly sure of any free reliable web hosters

Comment: are you hosting this locally or on a host?

Comment: Locally (I believe). When I watched the youtube video, I recall going to command prompt and opening up Host with my editor and typing, 127.0.0.1 mywebsite.localdomain

Answer (score 0):

This could be a matter of several things. If you are gonna send mails from your own computer or a self hosted server you need to make sure you are able to send mails. For this you need a service running.

How to get the service running is it's own story depending on what server you are running, what OS you have installed, and what free or paid mail services you have installed i personally like Mercury since it is already included in XAMPP that i use, but use some GoogleFu to find your own preferences. And a guide to set it up.

Now lets assume you have a mail service running already that is tested by eg. sending a mail through it to admin@localhost and you get the mail you want, but still don't get one through your web app, well this might be because of your anti virus, i know that McAffee and AVG Free is blocking mails sending this way, so try and disable the antivirus just for the send-out and of cause remember to activate it as soon as the mail is send, well for security reasons.

Comment: thank you for your input. In your opinion, do you think it's more ideal to pay a well-reputed and safe web-hoster than using my own? I had no idea that those factors you mentioned could be the issue. The thing I don't want to deactivate my anti-virus.

Comment: It would be like asking me if it is worth it having my own cow, to get milk. I'm pretty sure if i had my own cow, it would give amazing milk compare to store bought milk. But it would be expensive, and a lot of hard work, just for some milk. Well having your own server is expensive and a lot of hard work just to get a website hosted, let the farmer handle the milk production, because he takes care of a lot of cows and because of that it is more profitable, get your self a webhotel, do what you do best and make websites.

Comment: Thanks. I hear you. Besides, for a simple contact form and the fact that the website is for my future small self-employed business it isn't worth it.

Answer (score -1):

Here, you can find simple tutorial and sample code for contact form with php mailer class.

http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/01/how-to-create-contact-form-with-phpmailer-to-send-mails/